# Vaadin and Spring integration - @Inject doesn't work

Tags: spring, integration, vaadin, inject

I'm trying to integrate Vaadin with Spring. In my main Vaadin application class I have:

```
public class MyVaadinApplication extends UI {

@Inject
private PrivatePersonBo privatePersonBo;

@Override
public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    Layout layout = new FormLayout();
    layout.setCaption("New Private Person");
    setContent(layout);

    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring/Context.xml");
    appContext.getBean(MyVaadinApplication.class);
    PrivatePersonBo privatePersonBo = (PrivatePersonBo) appContext.getBean("privatePersonBo");
    PrivatePerson existingEmployee = privatePersonBo.findByName("TestUserName");

}

}
```

If I get bean from context directly I recieve bean, however If I comment line which recieves bean from appContext then @Inject annotation doesn't work and I get NullPointerException. My deployment descriptor is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:resources/spring/Context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>pl.adamsalata.MyVaadinApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VaadinApplicationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate Vaadin 7 with Spring in two simple steps:

1) **Create a `UIProvider` that lookup `UIs` in spring context:**

```
public class SpringUIProvider extends DefaultUIProvider {

     @Override
     public UI createInstance(UICreateEvent event) {
         ApplicationContext ctx =  WebApplicationContextUtils
              .getWebApplicationContext(VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext());

         return ctx.getBean(event.getUIClass());
     }
}
```

2) **Declare the `UIProvider` in web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
                <param-name>UIProvider</param-name>
                <param-value>org.example.SpringUIProvider</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And remember to use **prototype** scope for UI classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate Vaadin with Spring then use `@Configurable` feature. Then all instantiated objects (even if you create them using new MyObject() code) will be integrated with Spring context. You can find more details about such setup in Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj