# Why Vaadin @Autowired service returns null .?

Tags: spring, vaadin

here is my code

```
public class AddressbookUI extends UI {
    @Autowired
    private AddressService addressService;
```

.....in my method

```
            Contact contact=new Contact();
            contact.setName("Test");
            contact.setCity("Colombo");
            addressService.addContact(contact);
```

here is my service class

```
@Service
@Repository
public class AddressServiceImpl implements AddressService {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(contact);
    }

}
```

here is my spring context xml

```
<import resource="databaseContext.xml" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.priyan.vaadin" />
<context:spring-configured />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.priyan.vaadin" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
</bean>
```

here is my web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin UI to display</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>com.priyan.vaadin.AddressbookUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

all other things works fine.page also nicely loaded.
but when i press save button its come to that lines and at service call point its returns null

please help me to sort out this issue

thanks all

Comment: Mark AddressbookUI as `@Component`

Comment: Is `AddressbookUI` `@Configurable`?

Comment: @NikhilTalreja : Dear friend thanks for ur comment.I'll try with ur suggestion and let u know

Comment: @AndreiStefan : Dear friend thanks for ur comment too.I tried with @ configurable.but i put in service class.UI class can add @Configurable.?
I'll check and let u know

Comment: @NikhilTalreja : Still error same

Comment: @AndreiStefan : Still error same

Comment: Are your classes `AddressService, AddressServiceImpl and AddressbookUI`  covered in this scan: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.priyan.vaadin" />`

Comment: @NikhilTalreja yes dear friend.all classes included in same package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using the default `UIProvider` that instantiate `UIs` via `Class.newInstance()` so Spring container has no chances to autowire fields in your `AddressbookUI` class.

However, writing a `UIProvider` that create `UIs` via Spring container is a easy task and I already answer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269939/vaadin-and-spring-integration-inject-doesnt-work).

There are also some open source libraries that integrates Vaadin with Spring (including mine). Just search for Spring in [Vaadin Directory](https://vaadin.com/directory).

Answer (score 1):

`AddressbookUI` is not shown to be managed by spring. Is it instantiated with `new` ?

This bean must be instantiated and injected by spring for it's autowiring to be performed.

Comment: Thanks dear friend.But how to instantiated as per u say in spring context.xml.? can u please give me a suggestion. configurable & Component annotations not enough.?

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge, you can not use spring with vaadin out of the box.  it might fail at the very end on the scope vaadin is running with (close to session scope, but not really).  therefor you could use https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring to get this running.  once annotated with `@VaadinUI` your `UI` subclass will pick up the autowiring.

Comment: thanks for ur idea dear friend.its mean no solution exempt vaadin4spring